# TabBar item image size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller

In my app the user take a picture with the camera or from the library and then it will be displayed in the item bar.

Of course the image is not of the proper size of the tab bar item.

Currently I use a function to resize the image to 23x23 pixel. But in the retina display I see it blurred because I do not have 2x and 3x versions..

If I try to resize to 69x69 that is the 3x version, than I will see it in 96x96 so too big..

How can I fix this?

This is where I update the tab bar item images:

```
   let newImage = UIImage.resizeImage(image: image, targetSize: CGSize(width: 69, height: 69))
   print(UIScreen.main.scale)
   print(newImage.scale)
   items[items.count - 1].image = newImage.convertToGrayScale().withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
   items[items.count - 1].selectedImage = newImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

This is the function for resizing:

```
static func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let size = image.size

        let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / size.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height

        // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
        var newSize: CGSize
        if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
        } else {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio,  height: size.height * widthRatio)
        }

        // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

        // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
        image.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you try to multiply height and width of your image by [UIScreen mainScreen].scale (or Swift: UIScreen.main.scale)?

Comment: even if I resize to 69 that is 3x the size the image will be much bigger, it won't scale down automatically...

Comment: Then show you function's code.

Comment: @blyabtroi did it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using the UIScreen.main.scale factor in the resize function

```
// Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
```